# Calculate the percentage of a value in a logarithmic scale

Tags: javascript

I have a logarithmic scale going from 0 to 100:

```
  0.00
  0.10
  1.00
 10.00
100.00
```

I need to make a pie chart which has 4 quarters.
the first is going from 0 to 0.10
the second is from 0.10 to 1  etc.etc.

So if I have the value 25, it should be calculated which percentage this is in the logarithmic scale. Considering the scale it should end up somewhere in the last quarter of the chart.

Unfortunately my understanding of Maths does not reach this far ;)

Could you help out and tell me where to start.
I thought of looking at each quarter as a 100% piece, and then calculate where this might be in this quarter..

per example: 
32 > 10 so it should be in the last quarter (percentage wise above 75%)

So in this last quarter 32 will be in:

```
((32-10) x 100) / (100 - 10) = 24.44% in this quarter
```

Making this 24.44 / 4 = 6.11% over 4 quarters and thus 75 + 6.11 = 81.11% of the whole chart.

Now this would work, but I am looking for a shorter and simpler way of calculating this.

Can you please help out.

Answer (score 4):

This is surely a maths question about plotting values on a logarithmic
scale, and not really anything to do with JavaScript in particular or
programming in general. Anyhow ...

You need to decide on a minimum value, since the logarithm of zero is
undefined. Once you have your maximum and minimum logarithms, you can
scale your values as you wish. Slightly ontopic: JavaScript has
`Math.log10` in more up-to-date engines (and can be readily
defined if not, e.g. as in @NinaScholz's answer or using the [polyfill here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log10)).

```js
var minval = 0.01,
    maxval = 100,
    minlog = Math.log10(minval),
    maxlog = Math.log10(maxval),
    range = maxlog - minlog,
    lineartolog = function(n){
        return (Math.log10(n) - minlog) / range;
    },
    logplots = [
        0.01,
        0.1,
        1,
        3.2,
        10,
        32,
        75,
        100
    ].map(lineartolog);

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + logplots + '</pre>';
```

Adjust as required for percentages, radians, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Consideration:

```
       q0        q1        q2        q3
  01234567890123456789012345678901234567890
  |         |         |         |         |
0.01       0.1        1        10        100
                0.32      3.2        32

because log10(32) =    1.505 =  1 + 0.505
because log10(3.2) =   0.505 =  0 + 0.505
because log10(0.32) = -0,495 = -1 + 0.505
                                ^     ^
          quadrant after adding 2     amount to fill
```

together, fill is the amount in %:

```js
function log10(f) {
    return Math.log(f) / Math.log(10);
}

function getValue(v) {
    var l = log10(v),
        quadrant = Math.floor(l) + 2,
        fill = (l - Math.floor(l)) * 100;
    return { quadrant: quadrant, fill: fill };
}

console.log('0.32', getValue(0.32));
console.log('3.2', getValue(3.2));
console.log('32', getValue(32));
```