# How do I set the master volume level using SetMasterVolumeLevel in win32?

Tags: python, winapi, audio

I know about `ISimpleAudioVolume` and `SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar` but I am just trying to understand the math which is likely the reverse of [Calculate the percentage of a value in a logarithmic scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32136605/calculate-the-percentage-of-a-value-in-a-logarithmic-scale)

I am using Python PyCAW to call [`IAudioEndpointVolume::SetMasterVolumeLevel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/endpointvolume/nf-endpointvolume-iaudioendpointvolume-setmastervolumelevel)

I had this but it's not correct because it's putting in values that to not fit within the logarithmic scale that db uses

```
volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel( (max_db - min_db) * percent + min_db, None)
```

Comment: [`ISimpleAudioVolume::SetMasterVolume`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nf-audioclient-isimpleaudiovolume-setmastervolume) expects a normalized volume level in the range 0.0 to 1.0. You don't have to do any math if you already have a percentage in hand. [Audio-Tapered Volume Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/audio-tapered-volume-controls) has more detailed information.

Comment: I know about ISimpleAudioVolume, I am trying to figure out for the Core Audio that uses decibels

Comment: "I am trying to figure out for the Core Audio that uses decibels" You could try to use [IAudioEndpointVolume::SetMasterVolumeLevel method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/endpointvolume/nf-endpointvolume-iaudioendpointvolume-setmastervolumelevel) to set the master volume level.

Comment: SetMasterVolumeLevel takes in decibels but what I am trying to do is figure out the math from a % to decibel.  Basically what SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar does internally.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use the Scalar method, I found that `dB = 34 * math.log(volume_percentage / 100, 10)` works on my machine, the equation should be the same except for the `34`, you'll have to fine tune it. Also, `print(volume.GetVolumeRange())` will give you the minimum number of decibels. In my case it is -65.25 dB, you have to make an exception for it (or for a close number), since log of 0 is undefined. Hope this helps. Cheers.